# How to have relationship between entities from different xcdatamodeld in CoreData iOS obj-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, core-data-migration

1) Migration

Application which is already in appstore is having a single xcdatamodeld. But there is a requirement to separate existing database and to have 2 separate databases for UserData and AppData. Can anyone pls explain me on how to achieve this?

2) Relationship

Is it is possible to build relationship between these to separate database's entities?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are asking about db migration? Then [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html) explained by Apple .

Comment: I think this will helpful for you [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16146289/is-it-possilbe-to-have-mutliple-core-data-model-files-to-one-single-xcode-projec)

Comment: Thank you :) ll check these links